# ASP.NET Getting compiler error message intermittently

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an aspx page using only inline C# without a codebehind.
Running from Visual Studio it works, however adding the `aspx` file to the `wwwroot` of my local machine gives the message

> Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

If I rearrange the code to have the method above the code the message is instead

> CS1519: Invalid token 'try' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

I expect it is something to do with server configuration, though I don't really know where to start.

The issue only occurs if there is methods, removing `method1` from the below results in correct running.

This is the minimum entire file I was able to cause the error with

html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    try
    {
        string message = "Text";
        Response.Write(method1(message));
    }
    catch
    {
        Response.Write("Err");
    }

    string method1(string source)
    {
        return source;
    }
%>
```

Comment: So you have the error even when your code is this short? https://i.imgur.com/h7AiKtY.png hopefully you're creating your method outside of your Main or other method right?

Comment: @xTwisteDx you wouldn't have a `Main` method in an aspx

Comment: @xTwisteDx My code is in the .aspx file inline with the html, there is no explicit namespace/class/main in that file, I am unsure if they are implicit though. What I have pasted is cut down from what I am working with, but is an entire file that produces the same effect.

Comment: Ahh didn't realize it was .aspx. This one is outside my scope of knowledge.

Comment: If it's a compiler error, it's got nothing to do with server configuration. Your syntax for the code is simply not right.

Comment: @mason It is compiling happily when run within Visual Studio, I am assuming the issue is in the difference in configuration between the environment that sets up, and what exists in my localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have messed around with the Visual Studio project, running on an earlier version of .NET/C# yields the following error, It seems possible that this is the actual problem I have had

> Error  CS8059  Feature 'local functions' is not available in C# 6. Please use language version 7.0 or greater.

I am unsure why it thinks `method1` is a local function and details are hard to come by.

Edit: To solve my problem I put the method in script tags instead of embedded code blocks. The methods then could be used from the embedded blocks and the script tag.

```html
<script runat="server">
    string method1(string source)
    {
        return source;
    }
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're embedding code directly on the aspx page, that code still has to go in a method. Ex:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
    void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string message = "Text";
            Response.Write(method1(message));
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Write("Err");
        }
    }

    string method1(string source)
    {
        return source;
    }
%>
```

By the way - we don't typically put C# code directly in the .aspx file. That's what the [code behind](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303247/info-asp-net-code-behind-model-overview) system is for.

And we don't typically write directly to the response. It's hard to control where the markup will end up. In Web Forms, it's better to declare a control on the page and then add markup to that (or show/hide controls). Of course if we're going to talk about doing things well - then don't use Web Forms in the first place. It's a dead technology.

Comment: Adding the Page_Load as shown in the answer changed the error. It is now still getting CS1513, but there are [No relevant source lines] and it is in a file in "Temporary ASP.NET Files"

Comment: I removed the codebehind because I got tired of being unable to edit code while it was running (which I am able to do if not using a code behind), and it taking an age to restart compared to a refresh of the page.
What is currently preferred over Web Forms? Preferably without abandoning the ASP.NET/C# base.

Comment: ASP.NET Core - using either MVC Core or the Web API functionality combined with a JavaScript frontend such as Vue, React, or Angular.